# (Python) numpy genfromtxt convert problem

Tags: python, numpy, genfromtxt

i use

```
netdata = num.genfromtxt('resultscut.rw', dtype=None, delimiter = '|', usecols=(0,1,2,3,4))
```

to generate a list out of a text data file. This works really nice but when i put a bigger data file to convert i get this error:

```
  File "/home/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 2047, in genfromtxt
    for (i, conv) in enumerate(converters)]))
MemoryError
```

Is it too big for genfromtxt? How can i fix it?

Thank you in advance,
Greetings :)

Comment: Be specific. How big is the file that breaks the program? How big is the file that does not?

Comment: use `ls -l your_file` to find the size of it.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the resulting object is probably too large for your memory.

Numpy has the ability to store arrays on your disk (hopefully SSD, if you use a HDD, this will probably be too slow).
This is called a [memmap](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).

It is possible to store datatypes such as strings in a memmap, but this can become tricky: [numpy.memmap for an array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896747/numpy-memmap-for-an-array-of-strings)

Also, it might be complicated to get the data into the memmap in the first place. You might want to split the file and load it in multiple goes. Then you can write the individual portions into the memmap one by one.

Another important point might be the `dtype`. You specify `None` and use many columns. Are you having different datatypes in the different columns ? If yes, you might want to switch to [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), instead of numpy. That will give you a proper datatype for this spreadsheet like data. 
Be sure to use the appropriate datatypes for every column. That can significantly reduce your memory footprint (and might already solve your problem): https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/

To check the memory footprint of a numpy array, you can use `nbytes`:

```
np.ones((10,10), dtype="float64").nbytes # 800
np.ones((10,10), dtype="int32").nbytes # 400
```

Comment: Yeah i have strings and integer, but i want to have all as strings in the resulting array.

Comment: I'm not sure how numpy handles the dtype None, I would assume that it converts everything to object. If you specify str as a dtype, it should automatically convert the numbers. This might already be more space efficient.

Comment: Ok, thank you. It works with dtype=str aswell, altho it kills the program if the input file is getting too big. But i have the feelings it's faster now.